# Adding FileSystem::\\ to file path exports a blank CSV from SQL

Tags: sql, powershell, csv, filesystems, export

To start, this script worked as-is when I ran it through Powershell. It made it to the destination with all of the data.

```bsh
$adjustedDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
$dateString = Get-Date -Date $adjustedDate -UFormat "%m"
$dateString += " "
$dateString += Get-Date -Date $adjustedDate -UFormat "%d"
$dateString += " "
$dateString += Get-Date -Date $adjustedDate -UFormat "%y"

$query = "\\Drive\Folder\Folder\Folder\Insurance Status.sql"
$instanceName = "SQL-SERVER"

$csvFilePath = "\\Drive\Folder\Folder\Folder\Insurance Status "
$csvFilePath += $dateString
$csvFilePath += ".csv"

$results = Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile $query -Querytimeout 0 -ServerInstance $instanceName
$results | Export-Csv $csvFilePath -NoTypeInformation
```

However, when I ran it through the task scheduler, the task would complete successfully but the export file never made it to its destination in a mapped drive folder.

In order to get the task scheduler to export the CSV to a mapped drive I added "FileSystem:" to my path name.

```bsh
$adjustedDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
$dateString = Get-Date -Date $adjustedDate -UFormat "%m"
$dateString += " "
$dateString += Get-Date -Date $adjustedDate -UFormat "%d"
$dateString += " "
$dateString += Get-Date -Date $adjustedDate -UFormat "%y"

$query = "FileSystem::\\Drive\Folder\Folder\Folder\Insurance Status.sql"
$instanceName = "SQL-SERVER"

$csvFilePath = "FileSystem::\\Drive\Folder\Folder\Folder\Insurance Status "
$csvFilePath += $dateString
$csvFilePath += ".csv"

$results = Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile $query -Querytimeout 0 -ServerInstance $instanceName
$results | Export-Csv $csvFilePath -NoTypeInformation
```

Now, when I run it through the scheduler the CSV makes it to the mapped drive folder but the CSV is blank. What am I missing?

Comment: Rather than using `"FileSystem::\\Drive\"`  could you use `'\\server\drive$\'`; e.g. if your writing to the `c:\` drive of `MyFileShareServer` use `\\MyFileShareServer\c$\Folder\...`

Comment: Also you can simplify your creation of your CSV filename to a single line; e,g, `$csvFilePath = ('\\server\drive$\folder\folder\folder\Insurance Status {0:MM dd yyyy}.csv' -f (Get-Date).AddDays(-1))`

Comment: I tried doing this \\MyFileShareServer\c$\Folder\ (that was what I had originally) and it worked great when I ran it in powershell but did not work when I used the task scheduler. The only way that the task scheduler has worked thus far is to add the full file path including FileSystem:: but then for some reason that results in a blank CSV file and I have no idea why. Relatively new to Powershell so this is a bit beyond me.

Comment: What account does the scheduled task run under?  Does that account have write access to the share / folder?  Have you tried removing all complexiy; i.e. just have a task run a command that outputs a fixed string to a local file, then try outputting to the shared folder, then try dynamically building the path/filename, then add in the SQL output.  As you build things up, you'll spot which bit's failing.

Comment: Passing a string seems to work, it looks like its a problem with populating the SQL data. Not sure why the SQL would work without "FileSystem::" but not with it. I wouldn't think adding a full path would break SQL. And yes, the account has admin privileges and read/write.

Comment: To add to this, it runs perfectly when I kick off the script in powershell, but it fails when I kick it off from the microsoft "run" tool. Says " Export - Csv : Cannot open file because the current provider (Microsoft.sqlserver.management.PSProvider\sqlserver) cannot open a file. At C:'Powershell_Scripts\InsuranceStatus.Ps1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks For all of the feedback. I figured it out...

This was ultimately the code that fixed the problem:

```
$adjustedDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
$dateString = Get-Date -Date $adjustedDate -UFormat "%m"
$dateString += " "
$dateString += Get-Date -Date $adjustedDate -UFormat "%d"
$dateString += " "
$dateString += Get-Date -Date $adjustedDate -UFormat "%y"

$query = "\\Drive\Folder\Folder\Folder\Insurance Status.sql"
$instanceName = "SQL-SERVER"

$csvFilePath = "FileSystem::\\Drive\Folder\Folder\Folder\Insurance Status "
$csvFilePath += $dateString
$csvFilePath += ".csv"

$results = Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile $query -Querytimeout 0 -ServerInstance $instanceName
$results | Export-Csv $csvFilePath -NoTypeInformation
```

My real issue was upsettingly obvious. When I first ran into an issue with the task scheduler running the script I changed my scheduler credentials to the "admin" set, which I eventually realized did not have the proper credentials to access SQL server. After making the code change to include the full "FileSystem::" path and switching the credentials back to my standard user credentials everything worked fine. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The context of running the script within the Task Scheduler can change/have an effect on using the SQL Server module (sqlps/sqlserver). You do not specify what module you are using but `Invoke-Sqlcmd` exist in both modules.

In certain situations importing the sqlps module will change your path to be the SQLSERVER provider (`SQLSERVER:\`). When this happens it changes how you can access the local file system, it is no longer aware of the provider. This is why it requires adding `FILESYSTEM::` so it is aware of what provider you want to work with on exporting data.

The newer version of the `sqlserver` module they changed how the provider is used so it no longer changes the context/current directory to the SQLSERVER:\ provider. You might consider using that module and explicitly importing it in your script.

Comment: Hmm, not sure how I would do that? The frustrating thing is that I have run it as a .vbs, .bat, and .ps1 manually and they all run perfectly. Just can't get it to execute in the scheduler as a .vbs, .bat, or .ps1

Answer (score 0):

I think [@Shawn Melton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57404048/361842) hits the root of the problem.

In terms of what you can do about it, there are various options:

- The prompt changes to the SQLSERVER:\ drive when the SQL module is loaded; so you can load it at the start of your script, then change context.  E.g. below.  That's probably why you're seeing different behaviour in the scheduler; in your interactive PS session you've already loaded the module, so it's not loaded afresh each time you run the script.  In task scheduler, it's getting a new session each time it runs, so having to load the module each time.

```powershell
Import-Module SQLPS
Set-Location c:\ # or wherever; perhaps $PSScriptRoot if you're in a script; though that has no value if you're running code outside of a script file, so may be confusing if you're pasting code in the cmdline
```

- Or you can surround calls to the module's cmdlet with pushd/popd so that the current path gets reset after the call

```powershell
Push-Location c:\ # doesn't matter where, so long as it exists
Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile $query -Querytimeout 0 -ServerInstance $instanceName
Pop-Location # moves you back to where you were before you called Push-Location
```

- Or you can us a different approach.  Personally I hated the unpredictable side effect of using this module so much that I knocked up my own code:

```powershell
<#
TOPIC
    about_CCSqlServer

SHORT DESCRIPTION
    Executes SQL code against an MS SQL database.
#>
function Invoke-CCSqlCommand {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'ByQueryByConnection')]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'ByQueryByConnection')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'ByPathByConnection')]
        [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection]$Connection
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'ByQueryByConnectionString')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'ByPathByConnectionString')]
        [string]$ConnectionString
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'ByQueryByProperties')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'ByPathByProperties')]
        [string]$DbInstance
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'ByQueryByProperties')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'ByPathByProperties')]
        [string]$DbCatalog = 'master'
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'ByQueryByConnection')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'ByQueryByConnectionString')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'ByQueryByProperties')]
        [string]$Query
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'ByPathByConnection')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'ByPathByConnectionString')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'ByPathByProperties')]
        [string]$Path
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [hashtable]$Params = @{}
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [int]$CommandTimeoutSeconds = 30
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [int]$ConnectionTimeoutSeconds = 15
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'ByQueryByProperties')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'ByPathByProperties')]
        [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]
        [System.Management.Automation.Credential()]
        $Credential=[System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::Empty 
    )
    begin {
        if (! $Connection) {
            if ([System.String]::IsNullOrEmpty($ConnectionString)) {
                $ConnectionString = New-CCSqlConnectionString -DbInstance $DbInstance -DbCatalog $DbCatalog -ConnectionTimeoutSeconds $ConnectionTimeoutSeconds -Credential $Credential -AsString
            }
            $Connection = New-CCSqlConnection -ConnectionString $ConnectionString
        }
    }
    process {
        [hashtable]$splat = @{
            Connection = $Connection
            Params = $Params
            CommandTimeoutSeconds = $CommandTimeoutSeconds
        }
        [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand]$cmd = if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -like 'ByQuery*') {
                New-CCSqlCommand @splat -Query $Query  
            } else {
                New-CCSqlCommand @splat -Path $Path 
            }
        [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader]$reader = $cmd.ExecuteReader()
        while (($reader) -and (-not ($reader.IsClosed))) { #improve: consider using as reader rather than data table for better memory consuption with large data sets...
            [System.Data.DataTable]$table = new-object 'System.Data.DataTable'
            $table.Load($reader)
            #write-verbose "TableName: $($table.TableName)" #NB: table names aren't always available
            $table | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty RowError, RowState, Table, ItemArray, HasErrors
        }
    }
    end {
        if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -notlike '*ByConnection') {
            $connection.Close() #only close the connection if we own it; if it was passed to us, leave it open
        }
    }
}

function New-CCSqlCommand {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'ByQuery')]
    [OutputType('System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand')]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection]$Connection # Since the standard use case for this will be within Invoke-CCSqlQuery, and that works best by reusing an existing connection, we're best off only providing the conneciton option (at least for now)
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'ByQuery')]
        [string]$Query
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'ByPath')]
        [string]$Path
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [hashtable]$Params = @{}
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [int]$CommandTimeoutSeconds = 30 #30 is the default 
    )       
    $cmd = new-object -TypeName 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand'
    $cmd.Connection = $connection
    if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('CommandTimeoutSeconds')) {
        $cmd.CommandTimeout = $CommandTimeoutSeconds #https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx
    }
    #load in our query
    switch ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName) {
        'ByQuery' {$cmd.CommandText = $Query; break;}
        'ByPath' {$cmd.CommandText = Get-Content -Path $Path -Raw; break;}
        default {throw "ParameterSet $($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName) not recognised by Invoke-SQLQuery"}
    }
    #assign parameters as required 
    #NB: these don't need declare statements in our query; so a query of 'select @demo myDemo' would be sufficient for us to pass in a parameter with name @demo and have it used
    #we can also pass in parameters that don't exist; they're simply ignored (sometimes useful if writing generic code that has optional params)
    $Params.Keys | ForEach-Object{$cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@$_", $Params[$_]) | out-null}
    $cmd
}
function New-CCSqlConnection {
    [OutputType('System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection')]
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'ByConnectionString')]
    param (
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'ByConnectionString', Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$ConnectionString
        ,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'ByProperties', Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$DbInstance
        ,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'ByProperties', Mandatory = $false)]
        [string]$DbCatalog = 'master'
        ,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'ByProperties', Mandatory = $false)]
        [int]$ConnectionTimeoutSeconds = 15  #15 is the SQL default: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout(v=vs.110).aspx
        ,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'ByProperties', Mandatory = $false)]
        [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]
        [System.Management.Automation.Credential()]
        $Credential = [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::Empty 
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [Switch]$SuppressAutoOpen
    )
    if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'ByProperties') {
        $ConnectionString = New-CCSqlConnectionString -DbInstance $DbInstance -DbCatalog $DbCatalog -ConnectionTimeoutSeconds $ConnectionTimeoutSeconds -Credential $Credential -AsString
    }
    $connection = New-Object 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'
    $connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
    if (! $SuppressAutoOpen) {
        $connection.Open()    
    }
    $connection
}
function New-CCSqlConnectionString {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$DbInstance
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [string]$DbCatalog = 'master'
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [int]$ConnectionTimeoutSeconds = 15  #15 is the SQL default: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout(v=vs.110).aspx
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [System.Management.Automation.Credential()]
        [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$Credential = [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::Empty 
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [Switch]$AsString
    )
    #Useful document on possible properties: https://www.connectionstrings.com/all-sql-server-connection-string-keywords/
    $connectionString = ('Server={0};Database={1}' -f $DbInstance,$DbCatalog)
    if ($Credential -eq [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::Empty) {
        $connectionString = ('{0};Integrated Security=True' -f $connectionString)
    } else {
        $connectionString = ('{0};User Id={1};Password={2}' -f $connectionString, $Credential.UserName, $Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password)    
    }
    if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('ConnectionTimeoutSeconds')) {
        $connectionString = '{0};Connection Timeout={1}' -f $connectionString, $ConnectionTimeoutSeconds
    }
    if ($AsString) {
        $connectionString
    } else {
        [pscustomobject]@{ConnectionString=$connectionString}
    }
}

Invoke-CCSqlCommand -DbInstance $instanceName -Path $query -CommandTimeoutSeconds 0
Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile $query -Querytimeout 0 -ServerInstance $instanceName
```